# OCaml type inference does not yield expected type for function arguments

Tags: function, ocaml, type-inference

This is a homework. I know I shouldn't ask this here but explanation would be welcomed. :)

My code looks like that:

```
let some_function f x = match x with 
  | (k, v) -> fun k -> f k
```

`f` should be a function and `x` is a list of tuples.
My compiler (?) says it's
`('a -> 'b) -> 'c * 'd -> 'a -> 'b` but it should be `('a -> 'b) -> 'a * 'b -> 'a -> 'b`

You don't need to tell me the solution just explain me why it's `'c * 'd` and not `'a * 'b`

Answer (score 2):

First off, when you write this:

```
let some_function f x = match x with 
  | (k, v) -> fun k -> f k
```

You can pattern match directly in the function arguments.

```
let some_function f (k, v) = 
  fun k -> f k
```

Secondly, the `v` is never used, so let's get rid of that by using `_`.

```
let some_function f (k, _) = 
  fun k -> f k
```

This does exactly the same thing and gives us something easier to reason about.

However, the `k` in `fun k -> f k` shadows the `k` in the tuple argument to the function, so you're not really using that one *either*.

So we really have:

```
let some_function f (_, _) = 
  fun k -> f k
```

The concrete types of these are not known, so `f` is inferred to be a function that takes a value of type `'a` and returns a value of type `'b`. Therefore `f` is `'a -> 'b`.

That tuple that you never use? It has a type, but we can't know anything about those types from the rest of the function, so the inferred type is `'c * 'd`.

We can simplify this one step further.  `fun k -> f k` is equivalent to just writing `f`, so your function can be equivalently rewritten:

```
let some_function f (_, _) = f
```

Though this doesn't allow OCaml to infer that `f` is a function, so the type signature becomes:

```
'a -> 'b * 'c -> 'a
```

Comment: First of all: thank you sooo much for explaining the "fun" (hehe) to me! Didn't know that one before! But it's still not `('a -> 'b) -> 'a * 'b -> 'a -> 'b` or is it still the same? I thought I would make a difference :)

Comment: That doesn't apply _every_ time `fun` is used, but in this case it does.

Comment: OCaml is very algebra-y. If you saw `f(x) = g(x)` you'd know that `f = g`. IN this case you're essentially seeing the same thing. If you're creating an anonymous function with `fun` that takes on argument, and you apply a function to that same argument without modification, the anonymous function is the same as the function you're applying.